# Loading module at runtime works except under fabric

Tags: python, dynamic, fabric

I have 2 files in a directory: loader.py & mod1.py. Loader.py dynamically instanciates a class in mod1.py and calls a method on it. Here is mod1.py

```
  class MyClass1:
      def run(self):
          print "Class1 running"
```

Here is loader:

```
  def run():
      mod = __import__('mod1')
      cls = getattr(mod, 'MyClass1')
      inst = cls()
      inst.run()

  run()
```

If I run this just straight python: "python loader.py" I see:

```
Class1 running
```

Which is what you expect. If I then run it under fabric: "fab -f loader.py run" I see

```
Class1 running
Class1 running

Done.
```

Which makes sense, run() is called by fabric AND loader.py when it's loaded by fabric.

However, if I remove the explicit call to run in loader.py so it's only called once under fabric, I get

```
ImportError: No module named mod1
```

Why does running under fabric make a difference? Is there a way to make this work under fabric?

Comment: Would it help to add  an __init__.py file to the directory?

Comment: The mere existance of an __init__.py file did not make any difference.

Comment: Has the answer eventually helped? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my insight.

This weird behavior is explained in [docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/usage/fabfiles.html#fabfile-discovery), quote:

> Fabric does a normal import (actually an __import__) of your fabfile
>   in order to access its contents – it does not do any eval-ing or
>   similar. In order for this to work, Fabric temporarily adds the found
>   fabfile’s containing folder to the Python load path (and removes it
>   immediately afterwards.)

Look at the modified `loader.py`:

```
import os
import sys

print sys.path  # current dir is in sys.path

def run():
    print sys.path  # current dir is NOT in sys.path

    # no problem - we'll just add it
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

    mod = __import__('mod1')
    cls = getattr(mod, 'MyClass1')
    inst = cls()
    inst.run()
```

Looks ugly, but it fixes the problem.

[Here's](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/1.6/fabric/main.py#L135) how fabric does manipulations with imports while loading fab file. Also [this issue](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/256) is relevant.

Hope that helps.